# Expect script works fine in command line but does not work in cron job

Tags: python, linux, git, cron, expect

I have python script which call shell script like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([/path/to/script.sh], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output, error = p.communicate()
```

`expect` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set username "user"
set password "pass"
cd /my/repo
spawn /usr/bin/git pull origin master
expect "Username"
send "$username\r"
expect "Password"
send "$password\r"
interact
```

When I run py-script manually it works fine, I see output like:

```
Username for repo: user
Password for repo:
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
```

But when I run my script via cron I see this:

```
Username for repo: user
Password for repo:
```

And nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

My /etc/crontab file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

10 *    * * * my_username /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/python/script.py
```

Comment: How exactly do you define the `cron` job? Please [edit] your question to add information, don't answer in a comment. Does your real script specify an absolute directory at `cd /my/repo`?  Maybe you should show your real script. BTW: Your script is not a shell script but an expect script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `interact` to `expect -timeout -1 eof`.

`interact` only works when the Expect script is running on a tty but the cron job does not run on a tty.

You can verify this from an interactive shell:

```
# this works
expect -c 'spawn sleep 5; interact'

# this does not work
true | expect -c 'spawn sleep 5; interact'

# this works
true | expect -c 'spawn sleep 5; expect -timeout -1 eof'
```