# crontab doesn't run expect script

Tags: linux, shell, cron, admin, expect

my expect fils is:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn /usr/bin/ssh root@x.x.x.x "/root/raw/test.sh";expect "password:"; send "pass\n"; interact'
```

my cron setting for this expect script is

```
*/2 * * * * bash /home/myuser/myfolder/test.sh
```

when I run the expect script by using command  `./test.sh` in terminal I run ok but doesn't run in crontab

i have to mention i also execute the test.sh by using  `chmod +x test.sh`
what should I do to run the expect script in cron?

Comment: Do you really have that trailing quote in cron? You'll need to remove that.

Comment: What you **should** do: set up ssh keys to enable login without password, then in cron you would simply execute `ssh root@ip /root/raw/test.sh`

Comment: thanks again @glenn really i don't have such permission to do it.

Comment: You might explain to your supervisors that the alternative is to write the root password in a plain text file for all to see.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/60222681/900078

Answer (score 1):

2 problems:

1. there's no executable named "`/usr/bin/expect -f /home/myuser/myfolder/test.sh`"

   - you don't put quotes around the command in a crontab entry.
2. You want to invoke the script with the `expect` interpreter, but it's a shell script.

   - pick one of:

     1. `*/2 * * * * bash /home/myuser/myfolder/test.sh`
     2. make it an *expect* script

        ```bash
        #!/usr/bin/expect
        spawn ssh root@x.x.x.x "/root/raw/test.sh"
        expect "password:"
        send "pass\n"
        interact
        ```

Comment: really i am so appreciate for your time for responding me. really i did both of them but unfortunately not work for me please if you have time review the question again i change the structure of the code as you suggested although it didn't work