Control-M scp issue with file path name containing spaces
The following is my shell script to transfer TWO files using scp protocol.
The second scp statement shows the source file directory containing spaces (see line 10 where I added a backslash in Badge\ Docs to denote the subfolder name is "Badge Docs" (it has a space between the two words).
copy_data_reports.sh
# Copy revenue file
spawn scp ftpaccess@prod:/storage/revenue_bo/*Revenue.xlsx  /data/revenue_bo/
expect "ftpaccess@prod's password:\n"
send "mypass\n"
send "exit\n"
expect eof

# Copy PO_REPORT.xlsx
cd /data/storage/exp/Badge_Docs/
spawn scp -T ftpaccess@prod:"/storage/data/Badge\ Docs/PO_REPORT.xlsx" /data/storage/exp/Badge_Docs/
expect "ftpaccess@prod's password:\n"
send "mypass\n"
send "exit\n"
interact

The script works when I ran it in the Linux Server.  Both Revenue.xlsx and PO_REPORT.xlsx are picked up/refreshed in their corresponding destination folder.
Executing in linux - it is working
[linux_prd]$ ./copy_data_reports.sh
spawn scp ftpaccess@prod:/storage/revenue_bo/*Revenue.xlsx /data/revenue_bo/
ftpaccess@prod's password:
Revenue.xlsx                                                                           100%  130KB   1.5MB/s   00:00
spawn scp -T ftpaccess@prod:"/storage/data//Badge Docs/PO_REPORT.xlsx" /data/storage/exp/Badge_Docs/
ftpaccess@prod's password:
PO_REPORT.xlsx                                                                         100%   20MB  27.5MB/s   00:00

We have set up the copy_data_reports.sh to run via Control-M.   Control-M shows this script is executed without issues, BUT I see that only  the 'Revenue.xlsx' is being transmitted,  while  the second file (PO_REPORT.xlsx) is not being transmitted.   I am suspecting it might have something to do with the presence of the space in the originating path for the second scp statement  (the originating folder path for the first scp does NOT contain spaces, and it worked).
I made sure to enclose the originating folder path name in DOUBLE QUOTES (")  AND I kept the backslash to indicate that the path has a space in between ('Badge Docs).   Is there something I could have missed?

---- UPDATE -Below is the log file generated by running the copy_data_reports.sh via CONTROL-M:

spawn scp ftpaccess@prod:/storage/revenue_bo/*Revenue.xlsx /data/revenue_bo/
ftpaccess@prod's password:
Revenue.xlsx                                                                           100%  130KB   1.5MB/s   00:00
spawn scp -T ftpaccess@prod:"/storage/data//Badge Docs/PO_REPORT.xlsx" /data/storage/exp/Badge_Docs/
ftpaccess@prod's password:<eof>

Interestingly the script job triggered by CONTROL-M  seems to end abruptly while running the password execution for the second scp statement.
Is there any difference  running the scp shell script from Linux versus  the same script being triggered via the CONTROL-M?  I dont understand why the job triggered by CONTROL-M terminated prematurely,  as the log file from the Control-M run does not show any error messages.    Appreciate all helpful inputs.

The backslash is needed when your context is not quoted. When you're in a quoted context, the space is already marked literal instead of syntactic; no backslash is appropriate. (In single quotes this is true of all characters without exception; in double quotes there are some characters that still have special meaning if not quoted -- such as $ or " -- but space is still not among them).

Hi @CharlesDuffy, I did initially omitted  the backslash in the double-quoted file path for the 2nd scp statement  but when I executed it in linux it failed, so I had to put the backslash back in for it to work.    Still couldnt figure out why Control-M would not execute the second SCP statement in the shell script WHEN   just executing the shell script in Linux would work.

I updated my post by including the log file contents generated by the scp script job triggered by  CONTROL-M - the execution seemed to abruptly stop at the second scp execution  while 'waiting' for password input.   Not sure what is going on.

change interact to expect eof?

Thank you @sexpect-ExpectforShells - replacing 'interact' with 'expect eof' WORKS with CONTROL-M!   Interestingly enough,  Linux has no issue executing and transmitting the two files in the script - looks like Control-M is stricter when it comes to getting the expect script coded correctly.

the root cause should be similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60222681/900078

Someone suggested in the comment section above to replace 'interact' with 'expect eof'  and Control-M seems to like it - it finally worked.
# Copy revenue file
spawn scp ftpaccess@prod:/storage/revenue_bo/*Revenue.xlsx  /data/revenue_bo/
expect "ftpaccess@prod's password:\n"
send "mypass\n"
send "exit\n"
expect eof

# Copy PO_REPORT.xlsx
cd /data/storage/exp/Badge_Docs/
spawn scp -T ftpaccess@prod:"/storage/data/Badge\ Docs/PO_REPORT.xlsx" /data/storage/exp/Badge_Docs/
expect "ftpaccess@prod's password:\n"
send "mypass\n"
send "exit\n"
expect eof     # replacing "interact" -> works with Control-M

The output log generated when Control-M executed the script - it now shows PO_REPORT.xls being transmitted successfully:
spawn scp ftpaccess@prod:/storage/revenue_bo/*Revenue.xlsx /data/revenue_bo/
ftpaccess@prod's password:
Revenue.xlsx                                                                           100%  130KB   1.5MB/s   00:00
spawn scp -T ftpaccess@prod:"/storage/data//Badge Docs/PO_REPORT.xlsx" /data/storage/exp/Badge_Docs/
ftpaccess@prod's password:
PO_REPORT.xlsx                                                                         100%   20MB  27.5MB/s   00:00

Belatedly realizing, too, that looking at the last line of the log file I posted above of the CONTROL-M triggerd job showing ftpaccess@prod's password:<eof>  already giving a hint that I should have used  expect eof in the second “spawn scp” statement just as I did in the first “spawn scp” statement.  Lesson learned.
